# How can I write code to receive whole string from a device on rs232?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, 8051

I want to know how to write code which receives specific string.for example, this one  OK , in this I only need "OK" string.

Another string is also like OK
I have written code in keil c51 for at89s52 microcontroller which works but I need more reliable code.

I'm using interrupt for rx data from rs232 serial.

```
void _esp8266_getch() interrupt 4      //UART Rx.{
    if(TI){
        TI=0;
        xmit_bit=0;
        return ;
    }
    else
    {
        count=0;
        do
        {
            while(RI==0);
            rx_buff=SBUF;
        if(rx_buff==rx_data1)           //rx_data1 = 0X0D /CR
            {
                RI=0;
                while(RI==0);
                rx_buff=SBUF;
                if(rx_buff==rx_data2)           // rx_data2 = 0x0A /LF
                {
                    RI=0;
                    data_in_buffer=1;
                    if(loop_conti==1)
                    {
                        if(rec_bit_flag==1)
                        {
                            data_in_buffer=0;
                            loop_conti=0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(data_in_buffer==1)
                {

                    received[count]=rx_buff;  //my buffer in which storing string
                    rec_bit_flag=1;
                    count++;
                    loop_conti=1;
                    RI=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    loop_conti=0;
                    rec_bit_flag=0;
                    RI=0;
                }
            }
        }
        while(loop_conti==1);
    }
    rx_buff=0;
  }
```

Comment: Diffidently you should not implement do- while(any loops) in interrupt routine. Interrupt routine shall be as crisp as possible

Comment: did you mean uart instead of rs232?

Comment: Yes, rs 232 means uart

Comment: Yeah @Sudhee .I should not use do-while.than how could I write it? any example?

Answer (score 0):

This is one is just for reference, you need develop the logic further to  your needs. Moreover, design is depends on what value is received, is there any specific pattern and many more parameter. And this is not a tested code, I tried to give my idea on design, with this disclaimer here is the sample..

```
//Assuming you get - "OK<CR><LF>" in which <CR><LF> indicates the end of string steam

int nCount =0; 
int received[2][BUF_SIZE];              //used only 2 buffers, you can use more than 2, depending on how speed 
                                        //you receive and how fast you process it
int pingpong =0;
bool bRecFlag = FALSE;
int nNofbytes = 0;
void _esp8266_getch() interrupt 4      //UART Rx.
{
    if(TI){
        TI=0;
        xmit_bit=0;
        return ;
    }
    if(RI)                          // Rx interrupt
    {
        received[pingpong][nCount]=SBUF;    
        RI =0;                      
        if(nCount > 0)
        {
            //  check if you receive end of stream value
            if(received[pingpong][nCount-1] == 0x0D) && (received[pingpong][nCount] == 0x0A))
            {
                bRecFlag = TRUE;
                pingpong = (pingpong == 0);
                nNofbytes = nCount;
                nCount = 0;
                return;
            }
        }
        nCount++;
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{

    //  other stuff

    while(1)
    {
        // other stuff

        if(bRecFlag)        //String is completely received
        {
            buftouse = pingpong ? 0 : 1;    // when pingpong is 1, buff 0 will have last complete string  
                                            // when pingpong is 0, buff 1 will have last complete string  
            // copy to other buffer or do action on received[buftouse][] 
            bRecFlag = false;
        }

        // other stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sudhee, thanks for reference but I get any format string FROM BELOW  either 
1. <CR>< LF > "OK" <CR>< LF > OR
2."OK"<CR>< LF >

Comment: if you consider <CR><LF> as end of string, then this would work